# Convert query result from struct to string for another Golang package

Tags: sql, json, database, string, go

I have searched for a solution on the net and in SO, but found nothing that apply to return values. It is a simple sql query with several rows that I want to return. Error handling not included:

```
func Fetch(query string) (string) {

    type User struct{
        id string
        name string
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(query)

    users := make([]*User, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
      user := new(User)
      err := rows.Scan(&user.id, &user.name)
      users = append(users, user)
    }

    return(users)
}
```

I get this error when compiling:

> cannot use users (type []*User) as type string in return argument

How should I do to get a correct return value?

The expected input is

> JD John Doe --OR-- {id:"JD",name:"John Doe"}

Comment: The question is not clear, but I guest that your function returns string, but you are trying to return users.

Comment: @ThunderCat modified the question

Comment: The variable `users` has type `[]*User`.  The return type for the function is `string`.  It's not possible to return users from the function because a `[]*User` is not a `string`.  If you want to return a string, then you must format the slice of users to a string in some way.  If you want to return a slice of users, then move the `User` type declaration out of the function so it can be used in the return type for the function.

Comment: @ThunderCat " then you must format the slice of users to a string in some way." Any tip?

Comment: There are many possible ways to format a slice of users as text. Show an example of why you are looking for.

Comment: @ThunderCat For an example: JD John Doe (&id, &name)

Comment: @sibert Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54058668/edit) with the expected output. Hint: What you are referring to is still a data structure. How about changing the signature to `Fetch(string)([]*User)`?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your code:

```
type userSlice []*User

func (us userSlice) String() string{
    var s []string
    for _, u := range us {
        if u != nil {
            s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", u.id, u.name))
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(s, "\n")
}

type User struct{
  id string
  name string
}
```

In your Fetch function replace the last return statement like this:

```
func Fetch(query string) (string) {
  // Note that we declare the User type outside the function.
  rows, err := db.Query(query)

  users := make([]*User, 0)
  for rows.Next() {
    user := new(User)
    err := rows.Scan(&user.id, &user.name)
    users = append(users, user)
  }

  return(userSlice(users).String()) // Replace this line in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to return a String you can use the encoding/json package to serialize your user object, but you have to use fields that begin with capital letters for them to be exported. See the full example:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
)

func Fetch(query string) (string) {

    type User struct{
        Id string  // <-- CHANGED THIS LINE
        Name string // <-- CHANGED THIS LINE
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(query)

    users := make([]*User, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
      user := new(User)
      err := rows.Scan(&user.id, &user.name)
      users = append(users, user)
    }

    return(ToJSON(users)) // <-- CHANGED THIS LINE
}

func ToJSON(obj interface{}) (string) {
    res, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
      panic("error with json serialization " + err.Error())
    }
    return string(res)
}
```

Comment: There was no mention of JSON in the original question.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg He had the ability to read between the lines? :-)