# how to return a struct type into a string

Tags: go, type-conversion, go-gorm

I am not sure if this is ideal to do or even possible but here goes.

I am using gorm on my queries and I want to return the struct type into a string, the reason behind this, is because I am trying to handle the data which needs to match the front end.

This is what I am trying to do;

```
func (s *Storage) Query(items itemlisting.ItemsRequest) []itemlisting.ItemsRequest{
    var data []itemlisting.Item
    db := s.gdb

    db = db.Joins("LEFT JOIN trains ON trImId=imId").Where("trVehicleStatus= ? AND trImId= imId", "On hold")

    db = s.itemsQuery(request, db)

    db = db.Table("claims").Select(s.selectFields).Where("imId != ?", 0).Group("imId").Having("imId > ?", 0).Find(&data)

    // var dataMap map[string]interface{}
    convData, _ := json.Marshal(db)
    // json.Unmarshal(convData, &dataMap )
    // fmt.Printf(" JSON: %s\n", string(convData))

    return string(convData)

}

func (s *Storage) itemsQuery(request itemlisting.ItemsRequest, db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {

    s.selectFields = []string{"imId", "imStatus"}
    ...

    return db
}
```

Obvously the above wont work and I know I could probablly do something like this but that wont work either

```
func (s *Storage) Query(items itemlisting.ItemsRequest) string {
```

This is what I mean when I am saying handle the data;

```
func (s *server) HandleData(query string) []byte {

    var data []map[string]interface{}
    s.storage.DB().Raw(query).Scan(&data)

    var jsonArray []itemlisting.Item
    for _, row := range data {

        if row["imStatus"] == "Urgent" {
            x := true
            thisRow.UrgentItems = &x
        }

        jsonArray = append(jsonArray, thisRow)

    }
}
```

I am sure there must be another way around this without having to return a string but I am a pretty low level when it comes with golang so I am not quite sure which option is best

**UPDATE**

Thanks to this post [Convert query result from struct to string for another Golang package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058668/convert-query-result-from-struct-to-string-for-another-golang-package)
I managed to get this working but the format in which the results are coming through don't seem quite right, it seems more like a string rather then a json format

so done the following

```
func ToJSON(obj interface{}) string {
    res, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        panic("error with json serialization " + err.Error())
    }
    return string(res)
}
```

And slightly changed the `Query` function to return string

```
func (s *Storage) Query(items itemlisting.ItemsRequest) string {
  // Everything is the same as before
  // ...
  return string(convData) //<-- changed this
  return (ToJSON(data)) //<-- to this

}
```

The results before the changed looked like this and this was while I was returning a struct

```
func (s *Storage) Query(items itemlisting.ItemsRequest) []itemlisting.ItemsRequest {
...
return data
}

//Result
[
    {
        "imId": 1
    },
    {
        "imId": 2
    },
    {
        "imId": 3
    },
    {
        "imId": 4
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Which then became a string

```
"[{\"imId\":1},{\"imId\":2},{\"imId\":3},{\"imId\":4},{\"imId\":5},{\"imId\":6},{\"imId\":7},{\"imId\":8},{\"imId\":9},{\"imId\":10},
...
...
...
]"
```

I guess this is cuz I formated the json form to a string which is doing what is said to do but how can I do that without affecting the resulting json

Comment: please share [`MWE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That is going to take a lot in this case but I will try to do so @Chandan. Thank you

Comment: no need to create complete app just create one endpoint and try to regenerate the same which will take less time